# HTML5 data attributes casting null and undefined to string

Tags: javascript, html, casting, null, undefined

Consider the example code bellow from an HTML file:

```
 <div id="book"
     data-id="47909"
     data-title="Under The Dome" 
     data-author="Stephen King"
     data-year="2009">
 </div>
```

Selecting the book element with:

```
book = document.querySelector("#book");
```

Whenever I set some attribute to `null` or `undefined` it sets it to a string "null", "undefined" respectively:

```
book.dataset.author = null
typeof book.dataset.author
"string"

book.dataset.year = undefined
typeof book.dataset.year
"string"
```

While

```
let a = null;
typeof a
"object"

let b = undefined;
typeof b
"undefined"
```

Can someone please explain me why it behaves like this? Does it has to do with the fact that in the end everything will be converted to a string due to the nature of it being an element attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: An attribute value can only be a String. It is probably casting `null` and `undefined` to `String(null)` and `String(undefined)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [spec of dataset](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-dataset)

> On getting, the dataset IDL attribute must return a DOMStringMap whose
>   associated element is this element.

and as per [spec of DOMString's value](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-attribute-value)

> Attributes have a namespace (null or a non-empty string), namespace
>   prefix (null or a non-empty string), local name (a non-empty string),
>   **value (a string)**, and element (null or an element).

hence the value is **casted to String** before returning

```
String(null); //"null"
String(undefined); //"undefined"
String(1); //"1"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

> The HTMLElement.dataset property allows access, both in reading and
>   writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the
>   element, either in HTML or in the DOM.  It is a map of DOMString, one
>   entry for each custom data attribute.

In essence this means that all properties are cast to strings.

```
String(null)
// 'null'
String(undefined)
// 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

Point - 1: In below you make value `null`

```
book.dataset.author = null
```

It means you made value is `null`, but data type is `String` by default for datasets in HTML data type is `String`.

Point - 2: In below code

```
let a = null;
```

Value is `null`, but data type depends on value in JavaScript, so whenever the value is null by default it is an `Object`